# C# queueing dependant tasks to be processed by a thread pool

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I want to queue dependant tasks across several flows that need to be processed in order (in each flow). The flows can be processed in parallel.

To be specific, let's say I need two queues and I want the tasks in each queue to be processed in order. Here is sample pseudocode to illustrate the desired behavior:

```
Queue1_WorkItem wi1a=...;

enqueue wi1a;

... time passes ...

Queue1_WorkItem wi1b=...;

enqueue wi1b; // This must be processed after processing of item wi1a is complete

... time passes ...

Queue2_WorkItem wi2a=...;

enqueue wi2a; // This can be processed concurrently with the wi1a/wi1b

... time passes ...

Queue1_WorkItem wi1c=...;

enqueue wi1c; // This must be processed after processing of item wi1b is complete
```

Here is a diagram with arrows illustrating dependencies between work items:

[image]

The question is how do I do this using C# 4.0/.NET 4.0? Right now I have two worker threads, one per queue and I use a `BlockingCollection<>` for each queue. I would like to instead leverage the .NET thread pool and have worker threads process items concurrently (across flows), but serially within a flow. In other words I would like to be able to indicate that for example wi1b depends on completion of wi1a, without having to track completion and remember wi1a, when wi1b arrives. In other words, I just want to say, "I want to submit a work item for queue1, which is to be processed serially with other items I have already submitted for queue1, but possibly in parallel with work items submitted to other queues".

I hope this description made sense. If not please feel free to ask questions in the comments and I will update this question accordingly.

Thanks for reading.

**Update:**

To summarize "flawed" solutions so far, here are the solutions from the answers section that I cannot use and the reason(s) why I cannot use them:

TPL tasks require specifying the antecedent task for a `ContinueWith()`. I do not want to maintain knowledge of each queue's antecedent task when submitting a new task.

TDF ActionBlocks looked promising, but it would appear that items posted to an ActionBlock are processed in parallel. I need for the items for a particular queue to be processed serially.

**Update 2:**

RE: ActionBlocks

It would appear that setting the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` option to one prevents parallel processing of work items submitted to a single `ActionBlock`. Therefore it seems that having an `ActionBlock` per queue solves my problem with the only disadvantage being that this requires the installation and deployment of the TDF library from Microsoft and I was hoping for a pure .NET 4.0 solution. So far, this is the candidate accepted answer, unless someone can figure out a way to do this with a pure .NET 4.0 solution that doesn't degenerate to a worker thread per queue (which I am already using).

Comment: Have you looked at Task/ContinueWith?

Comment: I have and I noticed that ContinueWith requires knowledge of the prior task. I would like to not have to track antecedent tasks as specified in the original question, in part because I would have to do so per queue. Instead, I would like to "fire and forget" from the point of submission and deal with errors and error propagation in the task processing predicate(s). In other words, I want minimal state at the point of submission - the work item and the queue it should be submitted to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand you have many queues and don't want to tie up threads. You could have an [ActionBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684%28VS.110%29.aspx) per queue. The ActionBlock automates most of what you need: It processes work items serially, and only starts a Task when work is pending. When no work is pending, no Task/Thread is blocked.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, based on the documentation at the link you provided, this solution requires .NET 4.5 which has not yet been released. I am looking for a solution that leverages .NET 4.0 as specified in the tags attached to this question.

Comment: TPL Dataflow is readily available (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585582.aspx).

Comment: I have installed TPL Data flow and tried the sample code at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462696(v=vs.110).aspx. It would appear that items posted to an action block are processed in parallel and not serially as mentioned in your reply. This is not what I want - the items per queue must be processed serially.

Comment: I understand that. Pass ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 } to the constructor. I believe that the ActionBlock is exactly what you want and will cause very little work for you.

Comment: Ah, interesting, let me evaluate that possibility (i.e., MaxDegreeOfParallelism=1).

Comment: This seems to work and beautifully solve my problem at the expense of installing TDF, which is acceptable. I will play with it some more and if it works, you get the checkmark (unless someone gives me a pure .NET 4.0 solution that meets my question's constraints).

Comment: You can bin-deploy this lib (no installation). (Or implement your own slim version of ActionBlock).

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use the `Task Parallel Library (TPL)` and `Continuations`. A continuation not only allows you to create a flow of tasks but also handles your exceptions. This is a [great introduction](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152765/Task-Parallel-Library-1-of-n) to the TPL. But to give you some idea...

You can start a TPL task using

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    // Do some work here...
});
```

Now to start a second task when an antecedent task finishes (in error or successfully) you can use the `ContinueWith` method

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Antecedant Task"));
Task task2 = task1.ContinueWith(antTask => Console.WriteLine("Continuation..."));
```

So as soon as `task1` completes, fails or is cancelled `task2` 'fires-up' and starts running. Note that if `task1` had completed before reaching the second line of code `task2` would be scheduled to execute immediately. The `antTask` argument passed to the second lambda is a reference to the antecedent task. See [this link](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) for more detailed examples...

You can also pass continuations results from the antecedent task

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => 1)
    .ContinueWith(antTask => antTask.Result * 4)
    .ContinueWith(antTask => antTask.Result * 4)
    .ContinueWith(antTask =>Console.WriteLine(antTask.Result * 4)); // Prints 64.
```

Note. Be sure to read up on exception handling in the first link provided as this can lead a newcomer to TPL astray.

One last thing to look at in particular for what you want is child tasks. Child tasks are those which are created as `AttachedToParent`. In this case the continuation will not run until all child tasks have completed

```
TaskCreationOptions atp = TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { SomeMethod() }, atp);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { SomeOtherMethod() }, atp); 
}).ContinueWith( cont => { Console.WriteLine("Finished!") });
```

I hope this helps.

*Edit: Have you had a look at [`ConcurrentCollections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) in particular the `BlockngCollection<T>`. So in your case you might use something like*

```
public class TaskQueue : IDisposable
{
    BlockingCollection<Action> taskX = new BlockingCollection<Action>();

    public TaskQueue(int taskCount)
    {
        // Create and start new Task for each consumer.
        for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Consumer);  
    }

    public void Dispose() { taskX.CompleteAdding(); }

    public void EnqueueTask (Action action) { taskX.Add(Action); }

    void Consumer()
    {
        // This seq. that we are enumerating will BLOCK when no elements
        // are avalible and will end when CompleteAdding is called.
        foreach (Action action in taskX.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            action(); // Perform your task.
    }
}
```

Comment: The flaw here is that I do not want to keep any memory of task1 at the point that task2 is submitted. I just want to say that task2 should be submitted on queue1 after the last item I submitted, whatever that was. Therefore, I neither know nor want to track the antecedent task (task1) at the point of submission of the next task (task2).

Comment: Have a look at the child task section I just added. This may help you achieve what you require. All the best...

Comment: Are `SomeMethod()` and `SomeOtherMethod()` executed serially or in parallel? For my needs, they must be executed serially. Also, I do not have all tasks available at the same time. Work items come in and I Need to schedule them, so I can't do a `StartNew()` with multiple items.

Comment: They are executed 'in parralell' (although not in the strictest sense), they are in this case concurrent as there is no `task.Wait()` call. For these to execute sequentally, add `Task taskA = Task.Factiory.StartNew...;` then `taskA.Wait();`. I have added something about `ConcurrentCollections()`. I am no expert but i have used these to do a small queuing process in a small application and it worked well. This might help you here - or at the very least give you another avenue to persue. All the best...

Comment: Unfortunatelly, taskA.Wait() kills the deal for me. Also, as mentioned in the original question I am already using worker threads and a `BlockingCollection` from Concurrent Collections at the moment. Your TaskQueue solution looked promising, but in effect you are causing long running tasks to be created which are tying up threads from the thread pool for a long period of time - i.e., this method is equivalent to manual worker threads. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A .NET 4.0 solution based on TPL is possible, while hiding away the fact that it needs to store the parent task somewhere. For example:

```
class QueuePool
{
    private readonly Task[] _queues;

    public QueuePool(int queueCount)
    { _queues = new Task[queueCount]; }

    public void Enqueue(int queueIndex, Action action)
    {
        lock (_queues)
        {
           var parent = _queue[queueIndex];
           if (parent == null)
               _queues[queueIndex] = Task.Factory.StartNew(action);
           else
               _queues[queueIndex] = parent.ContinueWith(_ => action());
        }
    }
}
```

This is using a single lock for all queues, to illustrate the idea. In production code, however, I would use a lock per queue to reduce contention.

Comment: This is not good solution because ContinueWith will start the action inside the lock if parent task is already completed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the design you already have is good and working. Your worker threads (one per queue) are long-running so if you want to use Task's instead, specify `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` so you get a dedicated worker thread.

But there isn't really a need to use the ThreadPool here. It doesn't offer many benefits for long-running work.

Comment: The threads are long running, but the tasks themselves are short. Also, if I scale this to many queues, it will break down, because I can have oversubscription as all queues are processed concurrently. With a thread pool, I do not have to worry about this, since the tasks in parallel queues can be processed in parallel by the thread pool with minimal context switching.