# Winform running functions in parallel using backgroundworker possible?

Tags: c#, winforms, parallel-processing, backgroundworker

I need to run four funcitons in parallel while keeping the UI responsive and reporting progress, is background worker the optimum way of doing this? How can I do this in winform?

Comment: There is plenty of information on this all over the WWW. I would advise a much more complete search before asking such questions here...

Comment: I didn't find any example where parallel.invoke is used in background worker. I guess you can't do multiple task in background worker?...there reason for asking this was to see if i am on the right track. I have tried running four functions by starting threads, task and parallel.invoke behind a clickbutton event but none worked, as i was trying to acheive parllel exectuion but i am getting sequential execution. i wanted to know if i am doing something wrong starting background threads/task/parallel.invoke. as long as i dont update anything on screen this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) but I would recommend the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx). For what you want you could use something like the following

```
TaskCreationOptions atp = TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { SomeMethod() }, atp);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { SomeOtherMethod() }, atp); 
}).ContinueWith( cont => { Console.WriteLine("Finished!") });
```

This is using child tasks, here I have got two, you would use four. There are some limits to be aware of as the TPL uses the thread pool which has limits on the number of truly concurrent operations. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11229896/626442 and for more information on TPL and generic threading see

[J. Albahari's Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

and (for TPL specifically)

[This great tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152765/Task-Parallel-Library-1-of-n)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Use Task Parallel Library. You could run parallel tasks like

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => DoSomeWork(), () => DoSomeOtherWork());
```

And its gives you more options than Background Worker

More reference: [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The best method is to use `Task`s , which are a replacement for `BackgroundWorker`

You can see how to report progress from a `Task` here: http://nitoprograms.blogspot.co.il/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html

Comment: ok this tells about the reporting but how do i actually start multiple background task behind an event and wait for it to complete ?